# C++11 variadic template parameters notation in UML

Tags: c++, c++11, uml

Does anyone know how to model C++11 variadic template parameters correctly in UML 2.2?
I've seen a number of UML profile models as a result from web-search, that seem to describe the construct of 'any number of optional template parameters'. Or do I just confuse this with the fact that any usual template parameter might be optional when a default is provided in the declaration?

Can someone refer to appropriate links or specific sections of the UML 2.2/2.3 specs?

Here's a proposal I've been creating with [enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect):
[image: Variadic Template Parameters Model Sample]

**UPDATE:**
I'm especially interested in how the binding for unpacking mechanisms could be modeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, since nobody seems to have an answer I'm going to answer my question with what I've come up:

[image]

It's just a slightly modified model of the first proposal I gave in the question. At least with [enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect) I'm able to generate a syntactically correct and usable code skeleton. It's not possible to reverse engineer the generated code though.

Comment: This diagram doesn't look entirely _useful_ to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you try showing a better approach?

Comment: I don't have a better approach. I'm just saying that I don't think a UML diagram has any value here. I can't read it and deduce any useful information about the code you're going to write.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, may be not in this exemplary context. I've been asking for dis-/confirmation of the syntactical correctness (by means of UML).